# Get current system setting's fraction separator

Tags: c#, .net, localization, string-formatting

In my app I parse a value from xml (string) to a double.
The value in the xml happens to have the dot as a fraction seperator whereas the system takes the current system settings and can have a different separator (dev system takes the comma for example).

Is there a way to tell double.TryParse() the dot is the fraction separator?
Should I manually replace the dot with the system's fraction separator? If so, how do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` into `double.TryParse`:

```
double value;
bool success = double.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Float,
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               out value);
```

(For genuinely standard XML formatting, Frederik's suggestion of using [XmlConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx) is the best idea though.)

Answer (score 2):

What you should do, in this situation, is use the XmlConvert class and its members to convert the value like it exists in the XML file to a regular variable. :)

Comment: I didn't know such a thing existed. And why exactly is this class better then double.trypars()? I understand it can come in handy when there are special characters involved. But there is no tryparse as far as I can see.